# How to Select all possible distinct related "two-ways" values for any given ID from a junction table?

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, plsql, junction-table

table TBL_IN "IN Document details table"

| IID | IDate | ISubject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I-225 |  |  |
| I-300 |  |  |
| I-410 |  |  |

table TBL_OUT "OUT Document details table"

| OID | ODate | OSubject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O-20 |  |  |
| O-35 |  |  |

table TBL_INOUT "IN OUT Document Junction table"

| IOID | IID | OID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I-225 | O-20 |
| 2 | I-225 | O-35 |
| 3 | I-300 | O-35 |
| 4 | I-410 | O-20 |

Question is how to get the following query result in oracle sql or access query from the junction table?

query QRY_INOUT_Related "Select all possible related "two-ways" values for any given ID"

| ID | IO_Related |
| --- | --- |
| O-20 | I-225,I410,O-35,I-300 |

| ID | IO_Related |
| --- | --- |
| I-300 | O-35,I-225,O-20,I-410 |

I hope I clarified the idea as possible as I can.

Comment: Your results appear to include all the `IID` and `OID`. It may be more beneficial to have data that appears in distinct sets so that we can see when `IID` or `OID` would not appear in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you appear to want a hierarchical query that finds all the distinct connections via either `IID` or `OID` and then want to aggregate:

```sql
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS io_related
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, value
  FROM   (
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT oid AS id,
           iid,
           oid
    FROM   tbl_inout
    START WITH oid = 'O-20'
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR oid = oid
    OR PRIOR iid = iid
  )
  UNPIVOT(value FOR key IN (iid, oid))
  WHERE id <> value
)
GROUP BY id
```

Outputs:

> | ID | IO_RELATED |
> | --- | --- |
> | O-20 | I-225,I-300,I-410,O-35 |

and

```sql
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS io_related
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, value
  FROM   (
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT iid AS id,
           iid,
           oid
    FROM   tbl_inout
    START WITH iid = 'I-300'
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR oid = oid
    OR PRIOR iid = iid
  )
  UNPIVOT(value FOR key IN (iid, oid))
  WHERE id <> value
)
GROUP BY id
```

Outputs:

> | ID | IO_RELATED |
> | --- | --- |
> | I-300 | I-225,I-410,O-20,O-35 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1db850f31b9fdc0872bfaf14f4c8f182)*

Comment: Can you please convert your really great plsql code to MS-access query or any hint how i can search for it?

Comment: @lehyamaged I do not know ms-access so, no, I am unable to help you with that.

Comment: can we improve it so it can select all oid's in tbl_out ?

``` sql
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS io_related
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, value
  FROM   (
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT oid AS id,
           iid,
           oid
    FROM   tbl_inout
    START WITH oid = (select oid from tbl_out ) 
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR oid = oid
    OR PRIOR iid = iid
  )
  UNPIVOT(value FOR key IN (iid, oid))
  WHERE id <> value
)
GROUP BY id
```
@MT0

Comment: @lehyamaged Maybe use `START WITH oid IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')`? But if you have follow-up questions then you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [MRE] that includes the sample data, your attempt at a solution, the issues/errors with your solution and the expected output.