# How to Select all possible distinct related "two-ways" values for any given ID from a junction table? Modified

Tags: sql, oracle

My question is how to add the values `I-95`  as it related to `I-300`
and `I-390` as it relate to `I-20` to IO_RELATED output

The sample data is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TBL_IORELATE (ID, MainID, RelatedID) AS
SELECT 1, 'I-225', 'I-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'I-225', 'I-35' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'I-225', 'I-300' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'I-410', 'I-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'I-410', 'I-50' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'I-300', 'I-95' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'I-455', 'I-300' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'I-20', 'I-390' FROM DUAL;
```

The [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71126002/1509264) I want to adapt from my previous question is:

```sql
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS io_related
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, value
  FROM   (
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT MainID AS id,
           MainID,
           RelatedID
    FROM   TBL_IORELATE
    START WITH MainID  IN ('I-225')
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR MainID = MainID
    OR PRIOR RelatedID = RelatedID
  )
  UNPIVOT(value FOR key IN (MainID, RelatedID))
  WHERE id <> value
)
GROUP BY id
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ca7c8818edec39797c024cc1ae13999)

Comment: Hi, can you add what would be the expected result from your sample data please?

Comment: `ID IO_RELATED`

`I-225 I-20,I-300,I-35,I-410,I-455,I-50,I-95,I-390`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to any `mainid` to itself or `relatedid` and vice versa:

```sql
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS io_related
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, value
  FROM   (
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT MainID AS id,
           MainID,
           RelatedID
    FROM   TBL_IORELATE
    START WITH MainID  IN ('I-225')
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR MainID IN (RelatedID, MainID)
    OR PRIOR RelatedID IN (RelatedID, MainID)
  )
  UNPIVOT(value FOR key IN (MainID, RelatedID))
  WHERE id <> value
)
GROUP BY id
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | IO_RELATED |
> | --- | --- |
> | I-225 | I-20,I-300,I-35,I-390,I-410,I-455,I-50,I-95 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=08cf2b273bfa29f453b6a3a966d45bc9)*